# Debug Assertion Failed For MPI program for matrix multiplication with some threads

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpi

Good day. I have some issues with running MPI program that multiply matrices.
This is code (it is not my code) I get it from *http://dkl.cs.arizona.edu/teaching/csc522-fall16/examples/hybrid-openmp-mm.c*
I will be very grateful if you help me
Also I was looking for similar problems and solutions, but it didn't solve my problem

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAG 13

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double** A, ** B, ** C, * tmp;
    double startTime, endTime;
    int numElements, offset, stripSize, myrank, numnodes, N, i, j, k;
    int numThreads, chunkSize = 10;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numnodes);

    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    numThreads = atoi(argv[2]);  // difference from MPI: how many threads/rank?

    omp_set_num_threads(numThreads);  // OpenMP call to set threads per rank

    // allocate A, B, and C --- note that you want these to be
    // contiguously allocated.  Workers need less memory allocated.

    if (myrank == 0) {
        tmp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);
        A = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * N);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            A[i] = &tmp[i * N];
    }
    else {
        tmp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N / numnodes);
        A = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * N / numnodes);
        for (i = 0; i < N / numnodes; i++)
            A[i] = &tmp[i * N];
    }


    tmp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);
    B = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        B[i] = &tmp[i * N];


    if (myrank == 0) {
        tmp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);
        C = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * N);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            C[i] = &tmp[i * N];
    }
    else {
        tmp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N / numnodes);
        C = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * N / numnodes);
        for (i = 0; i < N / numnodes; i++)
            C[i] = &tmp[i * N];
    }

    if (myrank == 0) {
        // initialize A and B
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                A[i][j] = 1.0;
                B[i][j] = 1.0;
            }
        }
    }

    // start timer
    if (myrank == 0) {
        startTime = MPI_Wtime();
    }

    stripSize = N / numnodes;

    // send each node its piece of A -- note could be done via MPI_Scatter
    if (myrank == 0) {
        offset = stripSize;
        numElements = stripSize * N;
        for (i = 1; i < numnodes; i++) {
            MPI_Send(A[offset], numElements, MPI_DOUBLE, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            offset += stripSize;
        }
    }
    else {  // receive my part of A
        MPI_Recv(A[0], stripSize * N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }

    // everyone gets B
    MPI_Bcast(B[0], N * N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Let each process initialize C to zero 
    for (i = 0; i < stripSize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    // do the work---this is the primary difference from the pure MPI program
#pragma omp parallel for shared(A,B,C,numThreads) private(i,j,k) schedule (static, chunkSize)
    for (i = 0; i < stripSize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // master receives from workers  -- note could be done via MPI_Gather
    if (myrank == 0) {
        offset = stripSize;
        numElements = stripSize * N;
        for (i = 1; i < numnodes; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(C[offset], numElements, MPI_DOUBLE, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            offset += stripSize;
        }
    }
    else { // send my contribution to C
        MPI_Send(C[0], stripSize * N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // stop timer
    if (myrank == 0) {
        endTime = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("Time is %f\n", endTime - startTime);
    }

    // print out matrix here, if I'm the master
    if (myrank == 0 && N < 10) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                printf("%f ", C[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my issue
[image]
[image]

Comment: The program expects command-line arguments.  Did you provide them?

Comment: hmmm, really, it is possible and necessary to run the program through the command line and give parameters, instead of to start as usual project in studio. I'll try now

Comment: can you show how to do it through the command line? Very very thank you

Comment: You have two lines that uses the arguments given to the program: `N = atoi(argv[1])` and `numThreads = atoi(argv[2]);` If you don't supply those arguments, the program will have undefined behavior. For me it crashes if I don't supply them. Btw, the program leaks. Don't use `malloc` in a C++ program.

Comment: @Sviatoslavch The Visual Studio debug options has a place where to add the command line options.  Also, I would not have a lot of confidence in a program that did not check to see if you had the command parameters specified (checking the value of `argc`).  A good program would detect that you did not specify the arguments, and would output a "usage" or some sort of error message on the command-line stating that you are missing command-line arguments.  The program shouldn't just crash by assuming you had put those command arguments in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a `MPI_Bcast` on `B` as if it's a contiguous block of `N*N` elements. However, it's not: it's an array of pointers to `N` separate arrays for length `N`. So either you need to allocate `B` contiguously, or you need to do `N` broadcasts.